# Python Matplotlib subplot colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I have coded to produce four subplots. Each uses a third variable to color the point. Now I want to place color bar at right common to all four plots. Somehow I am unable to achieve this?

My present code and output:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 8   
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 8   
a=ax[0, 0].scatter(df['POA'],df['Inverter efficiency'],marker='.',c=df['Amb Temp'],label='Inv. Effi.',cmap='RdYlBu') #,cmap='gist_heat'
ax[0, 0].legend(loc='best')
ax[1, 0].scatter(df['POA'],df['System efficiency'],marker='*',c=df['Amb Temp'],label='Sys. Effi.',cmap='RdYlBu') #,cmap='gist_heat'
ax[1, 0].legend(loc='best')
ax[1, 0].set_xlabel("POA")
ax[0, 1].scatter(df['POA'],df['PR'],marker='.',c=df['Amb Temp'],label='PR',cmap='RdYlBu') #,cmap='gist_heat'
ax[0, 1].legend(loc='best')
ax[1, 1].scatter(df['POA'],df['dPOA'],marker='.',c=df['Amb Temp'],label='$\\frac{dG}{dt}$',cmap='RdYlBu') #,cmap='gist_heat'
ax[1, 1].legend(loc='best')
ax[1, 1].set_xlabel("POA")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.colorbar(a,ax=ax[:, -1], location='right')    
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.11, right=0.97, top=0.95, bottom=0.11)        
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you investigate [the example from the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html)?

Comment: @JohanC I did not come across this. Thanks a lot. I hope it solves the problem.

Comment: @JohanC One question. This examples uses `for' loops only it had same data. But I have different data like in my question. So how to proceed here.

Comment: `c=df['Amb Temp']` - You are using the same values to color the markers in each subplot. Is this a *sequence of numbers* as described for the `c` parameter in [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter)?

Comment: @wwii No. They are float values.

Comment: @JohanC I updated my question. I achieved 50% anwer.

Comment: @wwii I updated my question. I achieved 50% anwer.

Comment: What is the 50% that was not achieved? I only see one question.

Comment: @wwii I got the one common color bar but could not push to the right extreme. It is inbetween the plots.

Comment: @Mainland - look at the example in my answer it is similar to your example. See how the  colorbars are *made with* the figure instead of using `plt` and the `ax` argument is `ax=axs[1:, :]`. Play around with that and you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Mainland - try `ax=ax[:, -1]` .. see the edit to my answer.

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my code and with new result I got from your suggestion `ax[:,-1]`. It worked to enlarge the color bar but it did not move to right extreme.